# How do I number a 2D range of cells based on input from another range of cells?

Tags: vba

I have an input matrix consisting of 1s and 0s and I need to create a new matrix of  the same size with all of the cells  corresponding to the 0s being numbered 1 to n first and then the cells corresponding to the cells with 1s in them being numbered after the cells with 0 in them.

Any help anybody could offer would be greatly appreciated.

[image: input matrix]      [image: output matrix]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Worksheet.Function.CountIf` to do the whole range in one pass.

```
Cells.Clear
For i = 1 To 10
  For j = 1 To 10
    Cells(i, j) = Int(Rnd * 2)
  Next j
Next i
no0 = WorksheetFunction.CountIf([a1:j10], 0)
c0 = 1
c1 = 1
For i = 1 To 10
  For j = 1 To 10
    If Cells(i, j) = 0 Then
      Cells(i + 11, j) = c0
      c0 = c0 + 1
    Else
      Cells(i + 11, j) = no0 + c1
      c1 = c1 + 1
    End If
  Next j
Next i
```

With blanks as well:

```
Dim no0 As Integer, c0 As Integer, c1 As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim arrin(), rng As Range, c As Range
Cells.Clear
Set rng = [E8:H13]
Randomize
For Each c In rng
c.Value = Int(Rnd * 3)
If c.Value = 2 Then c.Value = ""
Next c
arrin = rng
no0 = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, 0)
c0 = 1
c1 = 1
For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
If arrin(i, j) = "" Then GoTo exitJ
If arrin(i, j) = 0 Then
Cells(i + 7, j + 9) = c0
c0 = c0 + 1
Else
Cells(i + 7, j + 9) = no0 + c1
c1 = c1 + 1
End If
exitJ: Next j
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks JMP. I'm now trying to extend the range of cells to include blank cells which return blank cells (i.e. if I don't need to use the whole matrix). Any ideas how to incorporate this into the code? I've edited the code as per comment belopw

Comment: `Sub Disp()
Dim no0 As Integer, c0 As Integer, c1 As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim arrin() As Variant
arrin() = Range("E8:F13").Value
no0 = WorksheetFunction.CountIf([E8:F13], 0)
c0 = 1
c1 = 1
For i = 1 To 6
  For j = 1 To 2
    If arrin(i, j) = 0 Then
      Cells(i + 7, j + 9) = c0
      c0 = c0 + 1
    Else
      Cells(i + 7, j + 9) = no0 + c1
      c1 = c1 + 1
    End If
  Next j
Next i
End Sub`

Answer (score 1):

Here's something simple that just offsets the results. It does loop twice though so it really depends on your data size but should be fine if just 1's and 0's.

```
Sub changenumbers()

Dim rng As Range, Counter As Long, cell As Range


Set rng = Range("A1:B6") 'Change range to suit needs
Counter = 1

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = 0 Then
        cell.Offset(, 4).Value = Counter 'Change offset to suit
        Counter = Counter + 1
    End If
Next
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = 1 Then
        cell.Offset(, 4).Value = Counter 'Change offset to suit
        Counter = Counter + 1
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This works fine I'm not sure what you're on about. I tested with different patterns and bigger set worked great. My first code was wrong because the 1's started from 10 instead of continuing from where the 0's finished. I miss-read the question.

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for the response. Can't seem to get this code to work though - just get a 2 in the first cell and a 1 in the last cell with all other cells blank?2 
 
 
 
 
 1

Comment: Do you have gaps or something else within the range? What is your actual range and where are you outputting? I don't know how you're getting that output.

Answer (score 1):

Try the next code, please. It assumes that the range to be analyzed is in columns A:B, and the processed result is dropped in C:D. It should be very fast, even for big ranges, the processing result is dropped at once:

```
Sub testNumberInputType()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, cel As Range, lastRow As Long
 Dim count0 As Long, count1 As Long, arr As Variant
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet: count1 = 9
 lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row on A:A column
 Set rng = sh.Range("A1:B" & lastRow)               'the range to be processed
 ReDim arr(1 To rng.Rows.count, 1 To rng.Columns.count) 'set the dimensions of the array to keep the processing result.
 
 'since the order of iteration in a range is left to right and then down
 'I took advantage and I could make a shorter piece of code, only counting
 'the occurrences:
 For Each cel In rng.cells
    If cel.value = 0 Then count0 = count0 + 1: arr(cel.row - rng.cells(1).row + 1, cel.Column) = count0
    If cel.value = 1 Then count1 = count1 + 1: arr(cel.row - rng.cells(1).row + 1, cel.Column) = count1
 Next
 'drop the result at once (the fastest method):
 sh.Range("C8").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).value = arr
End Sub
```

It considers (now) the empty cells like being 0(zero). The code can be easily adapted to skip such cells (if needed)...

If you need it to overwrite the existing range, you can simple replace `sh.Range("C1").Resize(` with `sh.Range("A1").Resize(`.

Comment: Thanks FaneDuru, I'm tryin to use the 0s and 1s in cells E8 to F27 (say) to number cells J8 to K27. When I update the cell references in your code I get a runtime error. 

'If cel.Value = 1 Then count1 = count1 + 1: arr(cel.Row, cel.Column) = count1'

Not sure what this is?

Comment: @sean whelan: Yes, so  it should be... I tried answering your question as I understood it, in order to make the shortest and more efficient code. I will adapt the code to work for any range. In principle, if the array is ReDimed according to the `rng` number of rows, this number is the same, but the `cell.row` will exceed the array dimensions. You can simple adapt the code replacing `cell.row` with `cell.row - 7`. But I will adapt the code to be able to accept any range. I will use the first range cell row as reference...

Comment: @sean whelan: Please, use the updated code. You may keep the 'C1' range to return, or not. The array content can be dropped wherever you need... And if 27 is the last row in column A:A, it will be determined by the code. If there are some other records below, you should manually build the range address. I will also edit the code and make some comments to make it easier to be understood.

Comment: @sean whelan: Didn't the above code answer your question?